# Computationally fastest way of merging data from multiple files into a single data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, parallel-processing

I am trying to read multiple files (more than 20000) from a directory and storing their data in a single dataframe. Their format is as follows, they all share the first column (note that numbers in the first column match file names, more on that later):

```
test = read.delim("814630", head = F)
head(test)
      V1   V2
1 814630 0.00
2 839260 1.95
3 841877 2.59
4 825359 4.95
5 834026 5.16
6 825107 6.21
```

Then I do this to read the files (in the example I just read 5 files):

```
> temp = list.files()
> length(temp)
[1] 20819
> start_time <- Sys.time()
> data = lapply(temp[1:5], read.delim, head=F)
> end_time <- Sys.time()
> end_time - start_time
Time difference of 0.1406569 secs
```

If I use `mclapply` from `parallel` package I get a similar time (when I do this for the 20000 files, it takes 15-20 mins, any advice on how to improve this time would help too):

```
> library(parallel)
> numCores <- detectCores()
> cl <- makeCluster(numCores)
> data = mclapply(temp[1:5], read.delim, head=F)
Time difference of 0.1495719 secs
```

Then I use `left_join` from `dplyr` package to merge them into a single data.frame.**This second part takes a short time with data from a few files, but when I try to merge all the data it takes much longer than even reading the files (it can take several hours).**

```
> test = data %>% reduce(left_join,by="V1")
Time difference of 0.05186105 secs
```

I guess there is some way of making it more efficient, but I do not have much experience optimizing repetitive tasks in R, any help would be much appreciated.

Also, here is how my final data.frame would look like after some formatting. Note that the data is a **symmetric matrix**. So maybe there is a way of only reading half of the data that could speed the process.

```
> row.names(test) = test[,1]
> test[,1] = NULL
> colnames(test) = temp[1:5]
> test = test[order(as.numeric(row.names(test))), order(as.numeric(names(test)))]
> 
> head(test)
         814630   814636   814637  814638   814639
814630     0.00   318.41 13293.00 2012.21   391.97
814636   318.41     0.00  1345.84 1377.79  1889.77
814637 13293.00  1345.84     0.00 6477.10 10638.69
814638  2012.21  1377.79  6477.10    0.00  3905.41
814639   391.97  1889.77 10638.69 3905.41     0.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach that assumes all the `V1` exist in every table:

```
library(dplyr)
V1 <- read.delim(temp[1], head=F) %>% arrange(V1) %>% dplyr::select(-V2)
data = lapply(temp[1:5], function(x) {
    read.delim(x, head=F) %>% arrange(V1) %>% dplyr::select(-V1)
})
test <- cbind(V1, do.call(cbind, data))
```

This will be much faster than repeatedly `left_join` since joining gets slower then more columns/rows you have.

Comment: I would also suggest using `data.table::fread` which is faster than `read.delim`.

Comment: Thanks! that works perfectly, and also using fread cuts the time in half.